# PHP DOM Parser in 'content_save_pre' filter

Tags: php, wordpress, dom

I have a Wordpress plugin that generate a PDF from the post's HTML after this is published.

The problem is that I need to perform some tests on the HTML before the plugin generates the PDF, and I can only use the DOM parser built in.

With the filter 'content_save_pre' I'm able to manipulate the post content and returning a simple string everything works. 
But if I try this code:

```
public function lintHTML( $post_content ) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML( $post_content );
    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

when I publish my post everything crashes and I got a 'This page isn't working' message on the browser.

When I go back to the post edit page everything seems to be okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$post_content is not a complete HTML document but an HTML fragment. The PHP DOMDocument will try and fix this before saving by embedding it into a proper HTML document.

```
$dom=new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<div>AAAA</div>');
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

yields:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><div>AAAA</div></body></html>
```

So you need to remove the 'padding' to get the transformed post content.

Comment: thank u, I tried to cut it but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: You do need to remove the 'padding' but there is something else also wrong. Can you dump the output of $dom->saveHTML() to the error log and show it in your question.